# Python Data Classes mapping to SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to map [Data Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to SQL Alchemy [declarative](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html) tables, but when I try to instantiate data class object, i have the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'runs.experiment_uuid' could not find table 'experiments' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'experiment_uuid'
```

SQL Alchemy tables definition:

```
class Experiment(Base):

    __tablename__ = "experiments"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    experiment_id = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    experiment_uuid = Column(Text, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    experiment_config = Column(JSONB)
    creation_date = Column(TIMESTAMP)

    runs = relationship("Run", lazy="select")


class Run(Base):
    __tablename__ = "runs"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "test"}

    run_id = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    run_uuid = Column(Text, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    experiment_uuid = Column(Text, ForeignKey(
            "experiments.experiment_uuid"))
    run_time = Column(TIMESTAMP)
    user_metadata = Column(JSONB, nullable=True)

    explanations = relationship("Explanation", lazy="select")
```

Data classes:

```
@dataclass
class Experiment:
    experiment_uuid: str
    experiment_config: dict
    creation_date: datetime


@dataclass
class Run:
    run_uuid: str
    experiment_uuid: str
    run_time: datetime
    user_metadata: dict
```

Mapping:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
mapper(Experiment, db_schema.Experiment.__table__)
mapper(Run, db_schema.Run.__table__)
```

And finally, when I try to instantiate and Experiment, I got the error:

```
self.experiment = Experiment(
        experiment_uuid=str(uuid.uuid1()),
        experiment_config=self.config,
        creation_date=datetime.now().timestamp()
        )
```

Comment: You got an error that looks oddly like an attribute assignment? It looks like there could be a good question in the hiding but not yet. Also, why are you even using a declarative class instead just a plain table object?

Comment: From SQLAlchemy 2.0, dataclass integration is ]supported out of the box](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html).